# Video tag does not take parent div width and height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a component like the one shown below with the video being played in the background.

[image]

But my video is going out of the parent div as shown below

[image]

Not sure why the video tag does not follow parent div dimensions.

### Current implementation

#### HTML

```
<div class="header">
   <video
      src="somevideo.mp4"
      class="header-video"
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      >
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
</div>
```

###CSS

```
.header {
  max-height: 655px;
}

.header-video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just try to add width and height to <video> as attributes.
<video width="100%" height="655px">

Comment: @DanielBednář tried that doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set height of the container `.header`

```css
.header {
  height: 120px;
}

.header-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header
{
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>text above</div>
<div class="header">
   <video
      src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-30s.mp4"
      class="header-video"
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      >
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
</div>
<div>resize me</div>
```

Or follow width or height:

```js
let video = document.querySelector("video");
function change(input)
{
  video.style[input.id] = input.checked ? "100%" : "unset";
}

change({id: "width"});
change({id: "height"});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 120px;
  width: 50vw
}

.header-video {
}

.header
{
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
<label>fit width<input id="width" type="checkbox" oninput="change(this)"/></label>
<label>fit height<input id="height" type="checkbox" oninput="change(this)"/></label>
</div>
<div class="header">
   <video
      src="https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-30s.mp4"
      class="header-video"
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      >
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>
</div>
<div>resize me</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the video take up all the width?

Comment: Use `object-fit:fill;` in `.header-video` to fill up the width. @HarshNagalla

Comment: yes, remove `height` from `.header-video` (added example)

Comment: @Terry Just checked there is object-fit:fill it works fine

Comment: @Terry There is both fill and cover property. In the fill property, the image is stretched to fill the given dimensions.

Comment: `fill` distorts the aspect ratio of the video: pretty sure that's not intended.

Comment: @Terry try `object-fit:cover;` won't distort the ratio.